# Move ToolStripItem down

Tags: c#, toolstrip, menustrip

I have a *custom-rendered* **ToolStrip** but the menu items are not where I want them to be. How do I move them down within render's code?

You *can't* change the **Bounds** property of the items and I don't want to subclass the items

[image http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5431/57405222.gif](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5431/57405222.gif)

Comment: I believe the two pixels are for the border. When I was playing with the custom-rendered, I noticed that I could paint outside the Bounds. Have you tried this? Paint a magenta rectange with different bounds. See what you get.

Comment: I don't get the problem, why not just change the Rectangle you pass to TextRenderer.DrawText?

Comment: @nobugz: I believe the way the render calls the paint events prevents the user from doing this. It has been about a year, and I may not remember correctly. I just remember that I gave up, and I am no stranger to custom OnPaint graphics, but this was the first time I used the custom renderer for the tool strip. I would love an answer then I can fix my control.